# stored procedure isn't get executed

Tags: jdbc, ejb

I really need your help. I have a JDBC code that calls an oracle stored procedure. This is the class that has the code:

```
public class DAOImpl {

    private String sql = "{call MAIN.SP_CALC(?,?,?,?,?)}";
    private Connection conn = null;

    public DAOImpl(Connection conn) {
        this.conn = conn;            
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void executeSP(String year, String month, Long id) throws SQLException {
       try (CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(sql);) {
           cs.setObject(1, id);
           cs.setObject(2, year);
           cs.setObject(3, month);
           cs.setObject(4, 0);
           cs.registerOutParameter(5, Types.INTEGER);
           cs.execute();
       }
    }

}
```

I have two clients for this class, a JavaSE Tester class and a stateless EJB. The JavaSE main() method have this code:

```
      try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            DAOImpl dao = new DAOImpl(conn);            
            dao.executeSP("2015", "02", 99561010l);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SPTester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

The stateless EJB has this other code:

```
        try {             
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            DAO dao = DAOImpl(conn);                
            dao.executeSP("2015", "02", 99561010l);                
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new SQLException(ex);
        } finally {                
            conn.close();
        }
```

ds is an instance variable injected to the EJB as a DataSource that comes from a JDBC Connection Pool declared in glassfish of type oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource. The variables DB_URL, USER, PASS of the JavaSE programm, have the same values that use the JDBC Connection Pool

As you'll notice, the only difference is the Connection object. Both JavaSE and EJB use the ojdbc6.jar driver. Both uses java 1.7.0_u2, that's why I use try-with-resources.

The problem is that only the JavaSE works! Both of them returns after some seconds of processing but only the JavaSE programm works. I have tried many things.. CMT and BMT EJB, wrapped and unwrapped types of id, synchronize and unsynchronize method, etc. I need this code working in the EJB :(

What's the wrong with my EJB?

thanks in advance

Comment: You forgot to elaborate how exactly the EJB didn't work. Was the transaction not committed or so?

Comment: hello BalusC, thank you for your answer. I will post now the EJB versions I did in CMT and BMT. With default CMT, I know that the container does a commit when the method ends, am I right? with BMT I did the commit explicitly. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

This is the CMT version of the EJB

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Interceptors({PropagateSessionContextInterceptor.class})
public class CalcBean extends BaseContextSessionBean {

@Resource(mappedName = "jdbc/maestro")
protected DataSource ds;
public Connection conn = null;

public void executeSP(String year, String month, Long id) throws SQLException {

   try {
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        DAO dao = DAOImpl(conn); 
        dao.executeSP("2015", "02", 99561010l);                                 
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new SQLException(ex);
    } finally {                
        conn.close();
    }


 }

}
```

This is the BMT version of the EJB

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Interceptors({PropagateSessionContextInterceptor.class})
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class CalcBean extends BaseContextSessionBean {

@Resource(mappedName = "jdbc/maestro")
protected DataSource ds;
public Connection conn = null;

@Resource
UserTransaction tx;

 public void executeSP(String year, String month, Long id) throws SQLException {
   try {
       try {
            tx.begin();
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            DAO dao = DAOImpl(conn); 
            dao.executeSP("2015", "02", 99561010l);                 
            tx.commit();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new SQLException(ex);
        } finally {                
            conn.close();
        }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       throw new EJBException(e);
   } 

 }

}

public class BaseContextSessionBean {

 @Resource
 public SessionContext ctx;

}

public class PropagateSessionContextInterceptor {

  @AroundInvoke
  public Object myInterceptor(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception
  {
   BaseContextSessionBean sb = (BaseContextSessionBean)ctx.getTarget();
   ControlListener.setSessionContext(sb.ctx);
   Object o = ctx.proceed();
   return o;
  }

}

public interface DAO { 
   public void executeSP(String year, String month, Long id) throws SQLException;
}
```

I don't know the reason of BaseContextSessionBean and PropagateSessionContextInterceptor. Originally, the EJB used a useless JDBC framework (that uses those classes), so I replaced it with the DAOImpl class. I use a DAO interface to decouple the implementation, the DaoImpl is been execute (in the EJB, the DAOImpl implements DAO, I forgot to put that in the earlier post)